# Meteor Hacks installing NPM Modules For Whole Team

Tags: json, node.js, meteor, npm, package

I've added meteorhacks:npm and included some packages in the `packages.json` file. Note the 's' on the end of packages, as this is needed by meteorhacks:npm.

Everything works for me but when I push to Git and the rest of the team pulls, they are unable to install the npm modules.

Because the json file is called packages.json they can't simply run `npm install` without renaming the packages.json file.

Is there some simple way they can install all the dependencies listed in the packages.json as well as the .meteor/packages